# Properties of exponential map of convex sum of metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Suppose we have a Riemannian manifold $M$ with two complete metrics $g_0$, $g_1$ such that their curvatures are bounded and injectivity radii are bounded away from zero.

My goal is to find a uniform lower bound away from zero for the injectivity radius of their convex sum
$$g_t:=(1-t)g_0+tg_1$$
for all $t\in[0,1]$.

What I want to try is that given $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, consider $exp_p^{g_t}(v)=exp_p^{(1-t)g_0+tg_1}(v)$.

I wonder if there are properties of exponential map which will be useful. For example,
$$exp_p^{tg}(v)=exp_p^{g}(tv)?$$
or
$$exp_p^{g_1+g_2}(v)=exp^{g_2}_{exp^{g_1}_p(v)}(Dexp_p^{g_1}(v))?$$

Also, It would be very helpful if I could get a reference for this topic.

Comment: The properties you are hoping for do not hold. I prefer to study the differential of the exponential map by formulating it in terms of Jacobi fields (you can find this explained in both other math.stackexchange.com posts and textbooks on Riemannian geometry).

Comment: @Deane Thank you for the comment! I will try those.